# The background of my text is going transparent

Tags: html, css

Im making an online game and was making the play button, but had the following issue:

What i want to achieve:

[image]

What is happening:

[image]

For some reason the background of the text is getting transparent...

HTML:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cta {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 45px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Ceviche One", sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  color: white;
  background: #6225e6;
  transition: 1s;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 0 black;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}

.cta:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.cta:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 #fbc638;
}

.cta span:nth-child(2) {
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.cta:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-right: 45px;
}

span {
  transform: skewX(15deg);
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="cta" href="#">
    <span>JUGAR</span>

  </a>
</div>
```

Any idea how to fix this? It works fine in codepen but not in my project.

Comment: In Chrome, I didn't see any transparency under your text. You mention it works in Codepen but not in your project, therefore there must be something else affecting the result in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are applying the color on class cta which is parent for the text JUGAR. You need to set the color to the span not a tag

Answer (score 0):

I was accidentaly applying a background-color to everything with *{}